# Magento2 - Lighttpd format - How to create a lighttpd config for magento2

Tags: magento2, lighttpd

I have working an nginx settings for magento2 but I'd like to know how to use too lighttpd.

I'd like you suggest everybody how we can create similar syntax like the following :

Nginx Block Syntax :

```
# Pub lines

location /pub/static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/pub/static/version {
        rewrite ^/pub/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /pub/static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/pub/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /pub/static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/pub/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /pub/static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/pub/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /pub/static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

# End Pub lines
```

Lighttp Block Syntax:

How to do the same with lighttpd syntax ?

Regards.

Ricardo / Brqx.

Comment: Hi again friends,

Answer (score 1):

Here a first option to setup lighttpd with magento2. I'll update once be improved.

-Brqx Magento 2 - Url Rewrite If No file

-url.rewrite-repeat allows for applying multiple (seperately defined) rewrite rules in a row
-url.rewrite-once will cause further rewrite rules to be skipped if the expression was matched

> url.rewrite-once = (
>
> "^/pub/static/(version\d*/)(.*)$"       => "/pub/static/$2" )
>
> url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
>
> "^/pub/static/(" + var.asset_file_regex + ")$" => "/pub/static.php?resource=$2",
>
> "^/pub/media/(" + var.asset_file_regex + ")$"  => "/pub/get.php?resource=$1",
>
> "^/setup"          => "/setup/index.php$1",
>
> "^/update"         => "/update/index.php$1",
>
> "(.*)"             => "/index.php$1"
>
> ```
> )
> ```

Here I put a github repo with a good format for Lighttpd for Magento2 :

https://gist.github.com/freestream/5bc28cfc716d1f9132f2

Also I have updated my KB with this problem and explained solution ( soon I'll create a github repo with all settings):

http://brqxportals.com/kb/systems/magento/versions/magento_20/pages/n01/m01_004-lighttpd_settings.html

Regards.

Ricardo / Brqx.